# ESET - ARP Cache Poisoning and Identical IP in network

Tags: networking, network-protocols, arp

My ESET SS5 Firewall kept detecting Identical IP address and ARP cache poisoning attack frequently (every 2 mins) from past 24 hours

I did some research on ARP cache poisoning attack, like how it can be used as MiM and using it as default gateway

So I intalled Wireshark and started capturing the network... 90% of the captured records are ARP broadcast packets from different sources to different destination. I learned(from a computer networks textbook) that modern ISP dont allow broadcast of packets, but interestingly 90% of the captured records are ARP packets.  Moreover 'Default Gateway' is generally the router/switch in the LAN, then in that case why is that different computers asking for different IP address' to respond with their MAC address' ??

If this was a networked area(a company) having network printer, then broadcasting and asking for who has this IP by ARP request might be reasonable. But in this case why will some one need a specific IP address unless its for some spoofing/hacking purpose.

These are the points that kept bugging me..Below are the questions

1. Will ISP's allow broadcast of ARP packets ??
2. Are the IP address that are ARP requesting other IP's in the LAN(same subnet 183.82.xx.xx ) be infected with a virus which is causing this ??
3. If there isnt a firewall, what can be the outcome?? - // Though lame but wanted to know

My knowledge about networking and hacking is half baked(still in the process of learning).

Answer (score 0):

1. Most ARP packets are broadcast packets, and ISPs have to allow this. Otherwise IP to MAC resolution will not be able to occur and no hosts will be able to communicate via IP.
2. Not necessarily, but could be. If you, A and B are sharing the same ISP gateway, and A wants to communicate with B, then A and B will have to resolve each other's IP addresses to MAC addresses. In doing so the ARP broadcast packets will be broadcasted to all hosts in the same IP subnet, including you.
3. ARP broadcast packets (in fact all IP broadcast packets) are broadcasted ONLY within the same IP subnet, and will never jump to a different IP subnet. Otherwise the whole Internet will break down due to a network storm of broadcast packets. In other words, even if you don't have a firewall configured, the ARP broadcast packets won't jump over from the WAN interface of your router to the LAN interface.

Now that I have written up all the answers, I am slightly confused. Where did you install Wireshark and on which interface are you capturing? If you are seeing ARP packets on your machine within the LAN, then the ARP broadcast packets must have originated from within, unless the router is mis-configured or broken in some way that it is letting ARP broadcast packets through from WAN to LAN. This is a VERY unlikely scenario.